# Maximum voltage on a metal sphere within a power switch

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, potential

A physics question asks: "You're developing a switch for high-voltage power lines.  The smallest part in your design is a 5.0cm diameter metal sphere.  What do you specify for the maximum potential on your switch if the electric field at the sphere's surface isn't to exceed the 3-MV/m breakdown field of air?"

I'm not looking for an answer, just want to be sure I'm thinking about this correctly.  Here's my analysis: (1) As to the magnitudes, voltage equals field times distance.  (2) For this problem, the relevant distance is the diameter of the sphere, not the radius.  If the sphere is part of a switch, presumably that means charge will be traveling from one point on the sphere to the point farthest away from the entry point, and that distance is the diameter.  (3) A publicly available answer uses the radius instead, but that seems wrong to me in this context.  The charge is not just traveling to the center of the sphere, it's going all the way across; radius is the right length to use in many other physics contexts, of course, but for this one diameter seems correct.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use the formulae for the Electric Potential and Field at the surface of a uniformly charged conducting sphere.

Comment: Thanks for the response which helped me think through this more clearly.  I suppose the right way to think about it is that if the sphere is in the switch, then the potential at any point on its surface will be whatever the maximum is set to be; and so we should use the formulas you mentioned to determine what the field at the surface would be for that voltage, which makes r the relevant quantity, not the diameter.  Thanks again.